# It is possibile open external terminal on VSCode with new iTerm2 window?

Tags: visual-studio-code, iterm2

I configured the settings.json and try to open the external terminal with iTerm2 in MacOS.

Can I open the terminal with iTerm2 in the new window even there was a iTerm window exists?
When I open the external terminal from the VSCode command. It will open current path with new tab in exist iTerm.

I try the same configuration in the Ubuntu with gnome-terminal. It will open with new gnome-terminal in stead of new tab in the exist terminal.

It is possible resolve this problem by configuring VSCode or iTerm2?

Comment: Is it not just `"terminal.external.osxExec": "iTerm2"` or `"terminal.external.osxExec": "iTerm2.app"` in [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson)? Also related: https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/2304

Comment: Yes, it is work for open the iTerm2 terminal. But in my situation, I want to open the iTerm terminal to the new window instead of the exist iTerm window in this Mac space [1]. [Note] The Mac space means like other Linux OS distro like the Gnome workspace [2] in Ubuntu. 
Refeerence:
[1] https://support.apple.com/en-ie/guide/mac-help/mh14112/mac 
[2] https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-workspaces.html.en

Comment: ah ok. I'm out of my depth here. my last comment: from googling "`command to open new iterm2 window instead of new tab in existing window`": https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/5869, and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/385199/how-to-create-a-hotkey-for-opening-a-new-iterm2-window (just possibly related. not sure if useful at all here).

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I'll read this material when I have the bandwidth.
Regards

Answer (score -3):

iTerm2 is a bit of a weird terminal, as it uses almost entirely tabs. You could theoretically download something like Alacritty or Kitty on your Mac, then just switch your configuration to those. Otherwise, a simple applescript should suffice for opening new windows